# Spark SQL 1.5.2 null checking doesnt work

Tags: apache-spark-sql, isnull

I face a strange behavior on Spark SQL 1.5.2, I have the following data:

```
val data: RDD[Row] = context.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
  Seq("show", "1234", 1465989124000l),
  Seq("show", "1235", 1465989124001l),
  Seq("show", "1236", 1465989124003l),
  Seq("show", "1237", 1465985524000l),
  Seq("end", "1238", 1465985524001l),
  Seq("show", "1239", 1465985524002l),
  Seq("show", "1240", 1465985524003l),
  Seq("show", "1241", 1465953124000l)
)).map(r => r :+ new DateTime(r(2)).getHourOfDay).map(Row.fromSeq)
val dataFrame: DataFrame = context.createDataFrame(data, StructType(Seq(
  StructField("eventType", DataTypes.StringType, nullable = false),
  StructField("eventId", DataTypes.StringType, nullable = false),
  StructField("eventTime", DataTypes.LongType, nullable = false),
  StructField("eventHour", DataTypes.IntegerType, nullable = false)
)))
```

when running the following query:

```
 val dataFrame1: DataFrame = dataFrame
        .cube("eventHour", "eventType")
        .agg(count("eventType"), countDistinct("eventType"))
        .where(expr("eventType is not null"))
```

I receive:

```
+---------+---------+----------------+-------------------------+
|eventHour|eventType|count(eventType)|COUNT(DISTINCT eventType)|
+---------+---------+----------------+-------------------------+
|        4|     null|               1|                        0|
|        4|     show|               1|                        1|
|       14|     null|               3|                        0|
|       13|      end|               1|                        1|
|     null|      end|               1|                        1|
|       13|     null|               4|                        0|
|       14|     show|               3|                        1|
|     null|     null|               8|                        0|
|       13|     show|               3|                        1|
|     null|     show|               7|                        1|
+---------+---------+----------------+-------------------------+
```

I expect to get the following data:

```
+---------+---------+----------------+-------------------------+
|eventHour|eventType|count(eventType)|COUNT(DISTINCT eventType)|
+---------+---------+----------------+-------------------------+
|        4|     show|               1|                        1|
|       13|      end|               1|                        1|
|     null|      end|               1|                        1|
|       14|     show|               3|                        1|
|       13|     show|               3|                        1|
|     null|     show|               7|                        1|
+---------+---------+----------------+-------------------------+
```

meaning filtering out all null values, but that doesnt happened. I just want to over come the null check issue since in actual code query is built dynamically and order is unknown (so I cant use rollup or group by)

I tried using `isNull` with same results.

Currently I check column type and decide what checks to make like:

```
dataFrame.schema.find(_.name == this.name).map(_.dataType match {
    case DataTypes.StringType => org.apache.spark.sql.functions.expr(s"length($name) > 0")
    case DataTypes.LongType | DataTypes.ShortType | DataTypes.IntegerType | DataTypes.ByteType => expr(s"$name > 0 or $name <= 0")
    case DataTypes.DoubleType | DataTypes.FloatType => expr(s"$name > 0.0 or $name <= 0.0")
    case DataTypes.BooleanType => expr(s"$name = true or $name = false")
    case DataTypes.DateType => expr(s"$name >= ${new Date(0)}")
```

Ugly but working, except the fact that empty strings are being filter out.